# Password change message appears on load in jsp

Tags: jsp, change-password

The following code for changing password runs successfully, but when the page loads the "Password change failed" message already appears. Once I reset the password it changes. I even tried using a hidden label but it still wont work.

```
    <form class="f1">
        <p class="a">
            <input type="text" name="oldpass" placeholder="Password">
             </p>
        <p class="a">
            <input type="password" name="newpwd" placeholder="New Password">
           </p>
            <p class="a">
            <input type="password" name="cnfrmpwd" placeholder="Confirm Password">
           </p>
           <br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="RESET">

 <%
            String olpass=request.getParameter("oldpass");
            String newpass=request.getParameter("newpwd");
            String conpass=request.getParameter("cnfrmpwd");
            Connection con;
            ResultSet rs=null;
            try{
             Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:D");
            PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from AOI.dbo.Login where Password='"+olpass+"'");
            rs=ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()){
            i=rs.getString(1);
            pas=rs.getString(2);}

            if(pas.equals(olpass)){
  PreparedStatement ps1=con.prepareStatement("update AOI.dbo.Login set Password='"+newpass+"' where Username='"+i+"'");
            int i1=ps1.executeUpdate();%>
        <p class="reset">Password has been Reset</p>
           <% } else {%>
         <p class="reset">Password change failed. Try again!</p>
           <% }
            }catch(Exception e){
            out.println(e);
            }
              %>
```

Comment: How can I do the above using Java Beans??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You are getting "Password change failed" because when you load the page. The else part executes so you are getting the message.
- When you load the page for first time,The request not contains any data. So `olpass` is null. You are comapring `pas` which you may be initialized to empty string like `String pass="";` So "" is not equal to null so else part excecutes.

**Solution :**

- Check for null before performing password check
- So you can change code like below to check null and password match

``` if(olpass!=null&&newpass!=null&&pas.equals(olpass))
{ //your code} 
else if(olpass!=null||newpass!=null|``(olpass!=null&&newpass!=null&&!pas.equals(olpass)))
{//your code} ```

Comment: Thanks,it worked when i added if(olpass!=null){code}. Neednt check the other parameters

Comment: Good,checking all parameter is like validation.Its your choice.